# SQL-Unable to display count value that contain 0

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, inner-join, query-builder

There is 2 Table Discussion and Comment, 
Discussion tablehas D1 and D2
Comment table has (C1,D2),(C2, D2)

```
SELECT        Discussion.DiscussionID, COUNT(Comment.CommentID) AS Expr1
FROM            Comment INNER JOIN
                     Discussion ON Comment.DiscussionID = Discussion.DiscussionID INNER JOIN
                     Category ON Discussion.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID
GROUP BY Discussion.DiscussionID
```

I want a output like this ...

```
Dicussion ID||   Comment COunt
D1                  0
D2                  2
```

but the the result like this

```
Dicussion ID||   Comment COunt
D2                  2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

convert the `Inner Join` to `Right Join` so will get all the rows from `Discussion` table.

```
SELECT Discussion.DiscussionID,
       Count(Comment.CommentID) AS Expr1
FROM   Comment
       RIGHT JOIN Discussion
               ON Comment.DiscussionID = Discussion.DiscussionID
       INNER JOIN Category
               ON Discussion.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID
GROUP  BY Discussion.DiscussionID
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use a Left Join

```
SELECT Discussion.DiscussionID,
       Count(Comment.CommentID) AS Expr1
FROM   Discussion
       INNER JOIN Category
               ON Discussion.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID
       LEFT JOIN Comment
               ON Comment.DiscussionID = Discussion.DiscussionID
GROUP  BY Discussion.DiscussionID
```